# Blender doesnt play ANY audio

Tags: audio

While creating my game in the bge
I think I just muted my blender with some hotkey, dont even know if its possible, but now all the audios from my game are muted.
Can someone help?

Comment: Send a screen shot of your logic bricks to see the settings and also which format are you using for the sound?

Comment: can you here the same audio files if assigned to a "speaker" and pressing ALT-A ?